# Kendo UI Angular Grid - Custom Headers

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

In the footer of a grid, you can do the following in each column and all the values will be in the same footer:

```
    <template kendoGridGroupFooterTemplate let-group="group" let-aggregates>
        <span class="pull-right">{{(aggregates["dProfit"].sum / aggregates["net_tot"].sum) * 100|number:'1.2-2'}}</span>
    </template>
```

Can you do this in a header?

- I have a Kendo Angular2 Slack: https://kendouiangular2.slack.com

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same with the GroupHeaderTemplate. Check it out - http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/GroupHeaderTemplateDirective/

Comment: I tried that but it only works if the GroupHeader is in the same column as the Group. I need to be able to make a custom header with values from different columns